Is it possible to give readonly access to a database during an upgrade
I am upgrading a sql server environment which has an application server, web server and a database server and I want to be be able to give my users readonly access to their data during the upgrade. Does anyone know if this is possible? and How could I do it?

Do not run in-place upgrade. Build a new server and perform a swap after upgrade.

It might be technically possible, but it would be fraught with Risks.
If you're upgrading Sql Server itself, you'll have to have downtime.
If you're making changes to table structures then you have to update the software reading those structures at the same time, so that's also downtime.
Upgrades tend to be "anti-social" processes, tearing things apart and putting them back together differently.  This is likely to "disrupt" application usage, even "read-only", making it appear "slow" and "unreliable" to Users.
And that works both ways, as well.  Significant normal, even "read-only", traffic might interfere with the upgrade itself.  If that fails part way through, you're into a "scary" place, trying to piece it back together again.
The upgrade process might also run for "some time" before reaching the tables that people are actively using.  When it gets there, the application either "hangs" or fails or disappears without trace, depending on its level of error handling.
Given the hassle all this "random disruption" will cause, it's just easier to announce a scheduled period of downtime, lock everybody out and get the upgrade done in peace and solitude.

SQL upgrade = downtime. Application upgrade: this could be done if you design your  application upgrades such that they can be modified without taking anything down, or even going into read-only mode. While possible--when's the last time you heard of Facebook or Amazon having scheduled downtime--this high-end DevOps tactic is by no means be easy to do!

Thank you Phil W.
